# .conkyrc files won't show up in Conky Manager

Tags: conky

So I've installed Conky and conky-manager. I downloaded the Harmatten themes for Conky, followed the instructions given here at [GitHub Conky theme](https://github.com/zagortenay333/Harmattan), but the `.conkyrc` files just won't show up when I click "Search For New Themes" in Conky Manager. I have no idea why. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think that's because this file is hidden, press ctrl+h. it might show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your conky themes are in the old format and your conky app is most likley the format check the ver. if its 1.10 its new format and will not work with Conky Manager. To check the ver. run the command:

`conky -v`

You could uninstall conky and go back to the old ver. 0.9 and the manager will work.